# Is it posible to Integrate web application to microsoft outlook or word?

Tags: outlook

Like how it asks email attachemnts to save directly to google drive or one drive . same way i want to get one more option that is my application.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to develop a Mail App which is based on JavaScript and HTML (+CSS). See [Mail add-ins for Outlook](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp161135.aspx) for more information in MSDN.

Also see [Word add-ins](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/dn833112.aspx).